# Django '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'NoneType'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm creating a site where users can bid on items, similar to ebay. For the actual view to allow them to bid (put a dollar amount in a form) I am having trouble getting the number to save. Currently though I'm getting a type error: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'NoneType'

I have tried doing int(float(my code)) but I'm not sure how to convert it into an int. I have tried many different ways but always get an error. If anyone can help me with the code I'd really appreciate it. I'm very new to Django.

Views.py

```
def new_bid(request, listingid):
    if request.method == "POST":
        listing = Listings.objects.get(pk=listingid)
        response = redirect("listingpage", listingid=listingid)
        try:
            bid = int(request.POST["bid"])
        except ValueError:
            response.set_cookie(
                "message", "Please input something before submitting the bid", max_age=3
            )
            return response
        if bid > listing.current_price():
            response.set_cookie("message", "Your bid was accepted", max_age=3)
            Bid.objects.create(bid=bid, listing=listing, user=request.user)
        else:
            response.set_cookie(
                "message", "Your bid should be higher than the current bid", max_age=3
            )
        return response
    else:
        return redirect("index")
```

models.py

```
class Listings(models.Model):

    listingid = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    starting_bid = models.IntegerField()
    bids = models.ManyToManyField('Bid', related_name='bids_in_the_auction', blank=True)
    last_bid = models.ForeignKey('Bid', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
related_name='last_bid_for_the_auction', blank=True,
                             null=True)

    def current_price(self):
        return self.listing_for_bid.last().bid


class Bid(models.Model):

    user = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    bid = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default='')
    listingid = models.ForeignKey('Listings', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
related_name='listing_for_bid')
```

Comment: You have to return an integer or float `current_price` it problem due to set `default=0` in `bid field` in `Bid` model and remove  `null=True` it will set the default value and in if the condition works as you expected. Try this once let me know in the comment

Comment: @l.b.vasoya thank you, I tried that but now I'm getting a different error, what I changed the models.py to is here and so is the error if you don't mind taking a look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65839225/django-error-valueerror-at-new-bid-1-cannot-assign-1-bid-listingid-must-b

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is a typo :

```
return self.listing_for_bid.last().bid
```

Should be just

```
return self.listing_for_bid.last.bid
```

as you just want to return a field value

Comment: thank you, I think I may have actually had the wrong thing there. I tried this but I'm getting a new error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65839225/django-error-valueerror-at-new-bid-1-cannot-assign-1-bid-listingid-must-b